# Where do I put my snaplets?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm new to Haskell and Snap and I want to write a simple bug-tracking application. I set up a Snap project using `$ snap init` and it works. The problem is that I don't know how to go any further.

I want to create a snaplet `Tickets` that uses a database to store bug reports, and use that snaplet in my main web application.

I read the documentation about snaplets but I couldn't figure out where to put their source code (in the `/snaplets` directory, I suppose? If so, how do I load them?). Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you need to create a separate snaplet for Tickets? The snaplet infrasructure is meant for **reusable** components such as session management, authentication, database access, admin panels, user management, etc.

Are you going to be using your Tickets self-contained module across multiple web applications? If so, then by all means go ahead and create a snaplet.

In any case, it sounds to me like you are at least in part asking how to organize a project with multiple "modules" or "parts" while using snap. I'll try to address this below. Please let me know if you feel I have missed the mark.

**Assuming you don't need to create a separate snaplet for Tickets:**

For functionality specific to a single site, I think you would be better off creating a few modules and developing the code for the functionality right inside your current application's package and module hierarchy. Here are a few points on how I have been organizing my snap projects of late:

- I put my database-related code under modules in `MyApp.DB.`
  namespace. You could have a `MyApp.DB.Tickets` that contains all
  database calls needed for operation on your Tickets module.
- I put all UI-related functionality under `MyApp.UI.` namespace. You
  could put a `MyApp.UI.Tickets` module that contains your `Handlers`,
  your `Splices`, your `Forms` and so on.
- To handle forms, I use the excellent [digestive-functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors) library. You may find this [blog post](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2012-04-03-digestive-functors-for-snap-users.html) helpful if you don't know them already.
- I usually have a shared UI helper library under `MyApp.UI.Helpers` where I place common code used across all/most UI modules.
- I usually have a shared Form helper library under `MyApp.UI.Forms`
- Any code tangential to the fact that my application exposes a Web UI goes outside the `MyApp.UI.` namespace. So if my application needs to perform some offline analyses, I may put them under the `MyApp.Analysis.` namespace.

Once you define and export your Handlers under `MyApp.UI.Tickets`, you can go to your `Site.hs` file and wire them into your application at specific routes.

For inspiration on how to handle database connections, you can check out the [postgresql-simple snaplet](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-postgresql-simple).

**However, if you do need to create a snaplet:**

A snaplet is simply a stand-alone application that uses the `Snap.Snaplet` infrastructure,  (typically) has its own `.cabal` file and (typically) is its own Haskell package. Snap then gives you a way to **embed** or **nest** this re-usable, self-contained application in yet another snap application. Think a hierarchy of [Russian dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Assuming you performed something similar to what I described in the section above, you are now 95% ready to convert to a snaplet. Just name your application snaplet-tickets, expose a `SnapletInit` using [`makeSnaplet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.8.1/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#t:Initializer) and use `nestSnaplet` in another snap application to include this reusable piece of functionality right there.

Comment: So if I want to create a snaplet, I would create a new application *snaplet-tickets* and expose it using `makeSnaplet`. How would I use it in my main application? Do I install it using cabal and then `import` it?

Comment: Yes, if you really have a reusable component that you want to make into a snaplet, then I'd put it in its own project.  My snaplets [snaplet-postgresql-simple](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-postgresql-simple) (not on hackage yet) and [snaplet-acid-state](https://github.com/mightybyte/snaplet-acid-state) are examples of how to do this.